# How to include a div in a JavaScript slide show?

Tags: javascript, css, slideshow

I have an image slideshow script in javascript. I want to include another icon infront of all the pictures. That means that the icon must remain in front of the other images and the slideshow must still work. Plz help me.

```
<div id="slides">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="slides_container">      
        <a href="images/product1.jpg" title="product1" ><img src="images/product1.jpg" width="380" height="262" alt="Slide 1"></a>
        <a href="images/product1.jpg" title="product1" ><img src="images/product1.jpg" width="380" height="262" alt="Slide 1"></a>
   </div>
   <a href="#" class="prev"><img src="images/arrow-prev.gif" width="10" height="67" alt="Arrow Prev"></a>
   <a href="#" class="next"><img src="images/arrow-next.gif" width="10" height="67" alt="Arrow Next"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#slides { position:relative; z-index:1;}
#top { position: absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:100;}
```

Change the `top` and `left` values to move the `#top` around.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give a lot to go on, but you can use CSS (positioning and z-index) to position your "icon" over the slideshow images.

depending on the shape of your "icon" / file type (use of transparency) may be an issue on older browsers.